# Umbraco Contour forms not displaying when inserted using the RTE and not sending any emails either

Tags: asp.net, forms, razor, umbraco, umbraco-contour

We just pushed out some updates to our Umbraco intranet site which is setup using a custom template and using Visual Studio. It seems to have broken Contour. The default "Contact Us" page and "Comments form" display the form title and a "Previous" and "Next" button when inserted using the RTE (Rich Text Editor). This is the code in the master page to for rendering macro when inserted using the RTE:

```
<umbraco:macro runat="server" language="cshtml">
@if (@Model.isContentBox)
{
   <div class="content-box">
       <div class="content-box-title">@Model.title</div>
            @Html.Raw(umbraco.library.RenderMacroContent(Model.bodyText.ToString(), Model.Id))
       </div>
}
else
{
  <h1>@Model.title</h1>
  @Html.Raw(umbraco.library.RenderMacroContent(Model.bodyText.ToString(), Model.Id))
}
```

All the asp.net content placeholders are set to runat server.

Two forms that were manually placed in the master page are visually rendering correctly but they are not sending out emails even though upon submission the user is notified that the form was successfully submitted. The message does appear in the backend under Contour > Forms > Report Inaccuracy > Entries. Code on the master page:

```
<umbraco:Macro ID="Macro2" runat="server" language="cshtml">
 @{
     var reportInaccuracyURL = Model.UrlName;
     reportInaccuracyURL = reportInaccuracyURL + "/report-inaccuracy.aspx";
  }
  <a href="@reportInaccuracyURL" class="button-small">Report an Inaccuracy</a>
</umbraco:Macro>
```

Entries in the web.config are still there with the correct smtp server and email address defined.

Keep in mind that these forms were working fine before we pushed the updates using Umbraco Courier. I don't understand where it is getting the "Previous" and "Next" buttons from.

Using Umbraco Version: 4.7.1 and Contour Version: 1.1.10

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank You.